# Column Visibility when Exporting to CSV

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work?

I have the "Column Visibility" set to "Show or hide based on an expression"

The expression is the following:

=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV",True,False)

Save to CSV, Column shows.

Answer (score 2):

Format options such as expressions on visibility are ignored for CSV rendering methods. CSV rendering methods are essentially data flows, so you can suppress elements that you don't want to include in CSV files by changing the DataElementOutput from Auto, the default value, to NoOutput.